# Why does caja sanitization of Google Apps Script htmloutput fail on particular strings

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-code-prettify, google-caja

I am trying to prepare GAS code samples for embedding in Google Sites and other web sites. I use the HtmlService.createHtmlOutput and HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile() and template.evaluate().getContent() to serve up an html version of the content of a google apps script. That all works fine as per [this post](http://excelramblings.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/publishing-google-apps-script-code.html).

Now I would like to prettify the code using prettyify.js. Im using the version [embedded in caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/doc/cajajs/prettify/?r=4554) and it almost works. However particular method names in the code being prettified throw an error from htmlservice.

> Untaming of guest constructed objects objects unsupported. Expect a
>   function not a string : pln

Specifically, this text is successfully prettified,

```
function xisItHtml (e) {
  return ( e.parameter.hasOwnPropertu('template')) ;
}
```

whereas this throws an error

```
function xisItHtml (e) {
  return ( e.parameter.hasOwnProperty('template')) ;
}
```

It seems that specific methods (strange because none of this code is being executed, just prettified), cause caja sanitation to complain.

The code in the template is just this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 // any jQueryness can happen here...
  try { 
    prettyPrint();
  }
  catch(err) {
    alert("failed prettification " + err);
  }
});
```

I'm pretty much stumped. any ideas?

Comment: both the working example and the one throwing an error look identical

Comment: The one that works has the hasOwnProperty spelt wrongly. If you spell it correctly it fails. Might be some checking for code being injected into html body?

Comment: Martin. If you copy your caja example into GAS html template and execute it, Example 1 works. The other 2 don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that there is a failure when you insert a prettified piece of text containing .toString() or .hasOwnProperty() into an htmloutput in GAS. I couldn't find any other text that caused problems but there may be more. My hack was just to change the text before prettification and change it back later.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // any jQueryness can happen here...
    var thingsThatScrewUp = [ 'toString', 'hasOwnProperty'],t;

    $('.pretty').each( function(i,elem) {
       var c = $(elem).text() ;
       // disguise
       for (var i = 0 ; i < thingsThatScrewUp.length ; i++ ) {
        c = c.replace(new RegExp("." + thingsThatScrewUp[i], 'g'),".sandw_" + i + "_ch");
       }
       try {
         t = prettyPrintOne(c);
       }
       catch (err) {
        $('#report').html(err + c);
       }
       // undisguise
       for (var i = 0 ; i < thingsThatScrewUp.length ; i++ ) {
         t = t.replace(new RegExp("sandw_" + i + "_ch", 'g'),thingsThatScrewUp[i]);
       }
       $(elem).html("<pre class='code pretty prettyprint'>" + t + "</pre>");
      });
      $('#working').html('Module:');
  });
```

Here's a  [Working version](https://script.google.com/a/macros/mcpher.com/s/AKfycbzig_MZJ4dF-LGkWlThc7-_U-AP6Jaf0iYfKR9QxoiKRUCzIxex/exec?module=vEquivalents&template=pretty)

Comment: `Authorization is required to perform that action.`